# ModelAttribute method for generic class

Tags: java, spring, generics, modelattribute

I want add this method in a generic controller used by my spring application:

```
@ModelAttribute("lista")
public List<E> populateList() {
  return serv.lista();
}
```

this method is part of this class:

```
public class basicController<E> {
  @Autowired
  private basicService<E> serv;

  protected Class<?> clazz;

  public basicController(Class<?> clazz) {
    this.clazz = clazz;
  }

  ...

}
```

But instead of `lista`, I want use the name of the class (`clazz.getSimpleName()` or otherwise).

Anyone have an idea of how to accomplish that?

Comment: @kocko I know that. But is there any way to accomplish what I want without use `clazz.getSimpleName`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think this is possible.

When working with annotations, the attribute values have to be [compile-time constant expression](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.28). And `clazz.getSimpleName()` is not a such.

Comment: Taking in consideration all the controllers derived from this class will have this same ModelAttribute method, how I could reference a specific `lista` in the view?

Comment: Probably you'd need to overload some methods annotated with different `@ModelAttribute`.

Comment: @KleberMota, this thread may be helpful: http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/web/111056-modelattribute-is-there-a-way-to-bind-it-to-generic-instead-of-a-static-model-type